# Delete Rows based on Duplicate Value in Column, Dated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet (currently 6000+ rows) with Column B that includes a date and Column J that is a doctor. Both columns will have repeated values. I'm trying to find a way (with VBA, as it is part of a much larger macro) to loop through doctors in Column J and select the most recent (based on date in Column B) entry. Then, it would delete all other rows with duplicate doctor names. Unfortunately, the amount of doctors are constantly fluctuating, so I can't specify certain ones to find as I have seen in some examples. For example:

```
Date           Doctor
2015-01-03     Bob  
2015-01-02     Jane
2015-01-02     Bob
2015-01-01     Jane
2015-01-01     Bob
```

Rows with duplicate Doctors will be deleted, leaving:

```
Date           Doctor
2015-01-03     Bob
2015-01-02     Jane
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you want to retain the **first** instance of a doctor??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, are you asking if rows are in reverse chronological order? It's pretty clear they want the most recent.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, the example was already descending, but the actual list is mixed. I suppose it would be possible to add in a sort function in the VBA for processing, then keep the first row containing the doctor's name and delete the rest. Do you have an example for this?

Comment: Nevermind, I went ahead and sorted them descending then used the .RemoveDuplicates code in order to remove multiple instances of the doctors. As long as you sort it first, it will keep the first (most recent) entry.

Answer (score 0):

Could you:

- move the list of doctors to a temporary workbook/sheet and remove duplicates?
- From there you could loop through your master list and input the greatest date for each doctor in the column next to the doctors name.
- Then loop through your master list again and check the date related to each instance.
- If that date doesn't match your greatest date from the first pass through, delete it, else, move on.
- At the end you would be left with your pared down list and you could just close and not save the temp workbook/sheet.

How large is your master set of doctors?

Comment: By master set, are you talking about a different workbook/spreadsheet? Or the original one? I'm not trying to compare against anything else.

Comment: I am talking about the original.